# crop image using rectangle dimensions

Tags: java, android, crop, android-bitmap

i'm trying to crop GIF animation,for that i started from cropping each bitmap of GIF,after croping the bitmaps i will store them in ArrayList but i have a problem with dimensions when i crop the image

[image]

what i get :

[image]

```
Rect rect = ((GIFCropper) findViewById(R.id.CropView)).getCropRect();
                final String srcPath = path;
                desPath = getDesPath(srcPath, cropIndex);
                GifDecoder gifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
                boolean isSucceeded = gifDecoder.load(path);
                if (isSucceeded) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < gifDecoder.frameNum(); ++i) {
                        croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(gifDecoder.frame(i), rect.centerY(), rect.centerX(), rect.width(), rect.height());
                        bitmapArrayList.add(croppedBmp);
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ensure the crop holder viewport maps correctly to the bitmap size

Then change this:

Bitmap.createBitmap(gifDecoder.frame(i), rect.**centerY()**, rect.**centerX()**, rect.width(), rect.height());

to this:

Bitmap.createBitmap(gifDecoder.frame(i), rect.**left**, rect.**top**, rect.width(), rect.height());